# Spring MVC and AngularJS integration

Tags: angularjs

I wanna know if it's good idea to integrate AngularJS and Spring MVC together to build a Java  web application. If so, how to do so ? The pros and cons of this.

regards

Comment: Spring MVC with REST? Or Spring MVC Web ?

Comment: Spring MVC with AngularJS not Spring REST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by Spring MVC you are referring to a Servlet based HTML solution like JSP, FTL, Velocity etc. I am going to consider JSP, because they are what every Servlet framework start with.

It is possible for you to wire things up with Spring MVC, but because of the difference in objectives of both technologies, there are going to be problems.

1. Angular JS is MVW framework in JavaScript which runs in a browser. JSP are compiled and executed in the Server.
2. Angular JS comes with a lot of functionalities in JavaScript to ease up the validations, page routing, cache management, .. actually what not!. In JSP you can use a tag library (jstl or so) and achieve the same functionality.. if there is no tag library, you can write scriptlets in it. But Angular runs in browser, so server does not take a hit
3. There is a considerable amount of interest in the direction of REST based web services, because of its ease to develop, maintain and change. Angular JS  supports this with a web framework that just works with REST.
4. JSP, however has its own advantages. Like the business rules are not exposed to the customer. There is a lot of Java EE related components which you can use, and though Angular JS does this from the browser, the JS is available in browser, where as the JSP code will not be.

Comment: Thank you for this good explanation, but this is a comparison between angular js and jsp indeed, but it's so good and explained well. Do you have an idea about the integration between spring web mvc (jsp based) and angularjs together (not spring rest ws)

Comment: Well, there is nothing that you will gain from it. You can load angular js in a script tag. Write your controllers and modules, but as soon as a page submit happens, boom! you will lose whatever you had in angular context. What is the technical problem that you are trying to overcome? May be if you tell that I might be able to suggest how to do it. From the context of Angular and Spring MVC, both are in different paradigms.

Comment: In fact I have a new project to start, I have already worked with spring MVC (jsp based) and I wanna use it for this project but together with angularjs. That's why I aked the question.

Comment: I don't recommend this, but it can be done. You will need to use the technologies smartly. But, the pollution in your code because of the integration will cost you more than the time you require to develop the application. Let me know if you need to know anything more about this.

Answer (score 1):

These links can help you:

[spring-security-and-angular-js](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/)

If you having idea to migrate JSP to angular. go [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/08/19/migrating-a-spring-web-mvc-application-from-jsp-to-angularjs)

Comment: This is a tuto about the integration between spring security and angular js, In facet I need to know the pros and cons of the solution mentioned above.

Comment: But the second link explains well the integration between them. I need to know the pros and cons of this architecture.